# JavaScript / Node Syntax Misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm working on a Node.js app. Everytime I think I understand JavaScript, a curve ball is thrown at me that I don't understand. Currently, I'm trying to use passport.js to authenticate a user. I have the following code (which works):

```
passport.authenticate('google')(req, res, function() {
  // TODO: Handle a user not authenticating

  // This is the happy path. It will always execute. However, it should only execute if a user authenticated with google.
  logger.info('user authenticated');
  res.redirect(307, '/auth-confirm');
});
```

My challenge is, I need to detect when a user fails to authenticate with Google. If they succeed, I need to get the access token. However, I do not know how to do either of these because I do not understand the syntax of this call. Specifically, I don't understand what `(req, res, function() {...})` is.

Is that line saying that passport.authenticate returns a function. So, req, res, and `function() { ... }` are passed as parameters to the function that `passport.authenticate` returns? If that's the case, I still don't know how to get the access token returned by google.

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what the syntax represents. For information about how to access the token, you should check the passport docs; I'd guess that it's passed as an argument to your callback.

Comment: Did you try this syntax :
  passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/auth-confirm',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));


http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

Comment: passport.authenticate doesnt return the function, it calls it when done. I find a lot of libraries poorly document callback parameters and it makes it hard to know what the parameters are. I am not familiar with passport, surely someone who is will be along soon, but sometimes when I get stuck like this I put in a bunch of parameters to the callback eg: function(p1, p2, p3, p4 etc.) { ... } and hit the debugger and look at them to see what they are

Comment: @DavePile: The code, as written, says that passport.authenticate accepts a single string argument. It then returns a function that accepts 3 arguments of which the third argument is a callback. You've missed the `)(`. However, after reading the passport documentation I can't find this use-case documented anywhere (it doesn't help that passport.authenticate behaves differently depending on how many arguments you give it.

Comment: @slebetman: thanks ;) I misread that